# How do I debug SAP ATC (ABAP Test cockpit) test runs?

Tags: testing, abap

I am running ATC (ABAP test cockpit) tests from SE80 ABAP workbench.

It is not the first time that I do not understand an ATC test result. (SAP standard check)
(I am a developer, without experience as ATC administrator)

What are good breakpoints to see how SAP tests ABAP code and/or emits test result to the ATC result list?

I find it hard to start an ATC test in the debugger from SE80, since the right mouse click to start ATC already invokes the debugger.

I have no rights for transaction ATC.

Comment: ATC wraps Code Inspector checks which are responsible of the checks (classes CL_CI_*, transaction SCI)

Comment: Do you have access to transaction sci ( sap code inspector)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to know which check is making you trouble. If you know, you can either find it via the classes ( CL_CI_* ) - which is kinda hard or you access the transaction "SCI".

In this transaction you go "Code Inspector" ->"Management Of" -> "Tests" and you should get the following screen:

[image: Code Inspector Checks]

Here you can find any check and category ( unfortunately I don't know how it is ordered ). Then you find your check, which is making you problems. For example: "Recognizing Dead Code" and you get the class ( in this case "CL_CI_TEST_CROSSREF" ).

Then you go into the method, which is called "run", and set a breakpoint there. The Run method is the one which gets called at the start of the test.

Then, when you check your code with ATC or SCI ( sci is the base of atc ) you will get into the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the accepted answer. It is correct and good.

If the debugger doesn't stop where you expect:

In an environment with a central ATC server, the tests are done with two different users: your own user and an RFC user.

To find out which RFC user, open two windows.
- start a longer running test in the first window
- open transaction SM50 to se which users are performing the tests.
Then set a breakpoint for the RFC user

In addition, in our system I experience the following:
If a check is performed by the RFC user, then a break point works for exactly one ATC run.
At the second run, it won't stop at the breakpoint. Remove and set the breakpoint, then it is good for one more ATC run.