# How to debug ATC Check

Tags: abap, sap-hr

i have to make a modification in ATC checks, but i don't know the class where the checks start.

Im talking about the check you start from SE80 -> rightclick on an object -> check (ATC) with...

i need the object set so i can delete some unwanted objects manually before the other checks start.

Does someone know the class or place where those checks start? Or where i can modify the object set before those checks?

greetings

What i've tried so far:

- /h debug right before exceute the check
- have a look at SATC_AC__UI_ONLINE_CHECK
- some various way to dive into the code of the checks
- tried this [How do I debug SAP ATC (ABAP Test cockpit) test runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58954761/how-do-i-debug-sap-atc-abap-test-cockpit-test-runs) but thats already after the point where i want to modify the object set.

all without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open your variant by going to T-code SCI. When you double-click on a configured check, the class responsible for that check will be opened.